# input text outside UL tag, possible?

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I am learning `framework7` and I wonder if it is possible to create an `input type="text"` outside `UL` tag. On the code below, the css is not rendering on my textfield. Please see code comments.

And here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/junryl/k5gd7Lww/1/).

```
<!-- THIS WILL WORK -->
<div class="list-block">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-input">
              <input type="text" name="name">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>   

<!-- NOW, WHAT IF WE WON'T SHOW TEXTFIELD IN INSIDE UL? -->
<!-- THE CSS WON'T WORK ANYMORE, IDK WHAT IS THE CORRECT CSS CLASS EITHER TO WRAP THE ELEMENT -->
<div class="content-block">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the input outside the list, you will lose the separating lines, but it is possible adding the required classes:

```
<!-- THIS WILL WORK -->
<div class="list-block">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-input">
              <input type="text" name="name">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>   

<!-- NOW, WHAT IF WE WON'T SHOW TEXTFIELD IN INSIDE UL? -->
<div class="content-block list-block">
  <div class="item-input">
      <input type="text" value="text here" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here: https://jsfiddle.net/k5gd7Lww/10/